# How to open (View) a file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I am using XAMPP Virtual Server. In my PHP code, I  create a word document and write to it. The document is saved in the same directory of the php file. Now, after I've written to this document, I want it to automatically open, so that the user can view it. Is that possible in PHP? If so, then How? Below is the part that opens the file and writes to it. I am missing the file view part. Thank you.

```
$fp = fopen( $fileName, 'w+');
fwrite($fp, $report);
```

Note: I don't want to download the file. (Consider that the server and the client is the same machine). I just want the file to open.

Comment: I think you need to send the document to the user as a download.

Comment: No I don't want to download it. Consider that the server is on the same machine as the client. (The XAMPP virtual server).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `header("location: file:///C:\xampp\public_html\docs\worddocument.doc");`

Comment: I tried this. It gave no errors, but it didn't work.

 header('location: file:///C\xampp\htdocs\ers//'.$fileName);

Comment: Well, there are so much security issues that would prevent a thing like this.
Usually browsers don't allow access to local files, it was a long shot, but aparently a no shot.
Only other solution is to download the file.

Comment: Ow, try `exec('C:\program files\office\winword.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\ers....');`, make sure Xampp runs under the same user as that you are using.

Comment: And you forgot the : between C and \xampp

Comment: OK, so the (server?) running PHP has written a .doc file (locally), and you want it to be automatically opened for someone on the same machine (not on a remote browser)? exec() or something similar should be able to start Word (check the paths carefully for both Word and the new .doc file). However, it is possible that there will be some conflict between the browser and Word trying to open up as a child of the browser. You may be seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, didn't ever done this, but it worked:

```
`notepad c:/xampp/htdocs/bitnami.css`;
```

This is for the case that you want that PHP opens others apps. Be aware of the execution time limit of the PHP.